# JPEG byte array values not as expected for JPEG

Tags: android, formatting, jpeg

If I understand correctly, a Jpeg file should start with
    0xff
    0xd8  Start of File Marker

then
0xff
more markers

If I convert a bitmap to ByteArray and look at it with Eclipse Expressions it doesn't  look right

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
SaveFileBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
byte[] Image1Byte = bos.toByteArray();
```

Image1Byte
    [0] -1
    [1] -40
    [2] -1
    [3] -32
    [4] 0
    [5] 16

I thought it should read

Image1Byte
    [0] 255
    [1] 216 (Start of file marker)
    [2] 255
    [3] (next Marker)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you use unsigned byte values for the comparison (currently you are using signed byte values).

Answer (score 3):

In Java byte values are signed, they go from -128 to 127.

The data you see are correct: the bit patterns of -1 and 255 are the same, so are -40 and 216.

Comment: Trippy. Thank you very much.  I REALLY appreciate the help.  I also appreciate you not laughing at my ignorance.  Enjoy!    Odd, it will not let me vote on your answer.

Comment: @user1133277 I believe you need 15 rep to up-vote... although you should be able to accept the answer.